# Can i change/use different IP,s in jmeter while using/testing hls streaming?

Tags: jmeter, ip, http-live-streaming, jmeter-plugins

I am using jmeter for hls streaming load testing. How can I use different IP's for testing hls streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go for "normal" [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for testing your HLS server you can specify source IP address(es) in the relevant field of the "Advanced" tab

[image: JMeter Source IP address]

Check out [How to Load Test HTTP Live Media Streaming (HLS) with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-http-live-media-streaming-hls-jmeter) article for more information on how to configure JMeter for HLS testing using HTTP Request samplers.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri! I got it